# When I try to delete file in my PC it gives the error "Item not found"

Tags: windows-7

When I try to delete file in my PC it gives the error

> Could not find this item
>   This is no longer located in C:\Users\1600\Downloads. Verify the item's located and try again

File shows 0KB size.

Comment: Have you tried running `chkdsk` in case of any problems?

Comment: You could try deleting via cmd if that makes a difference too.

Comment: Try this software if you are on a PC: http://www.gibinsoft.net/gipoutils/fileutil/

Comment:  The ONLY THING that worked was compressing it and having WINRAR or 7ZIP do the deletion. It sounds weird, but this worked. Confirmed here: https://superuser.com/q/787580/169199

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to delete it in Safe Mode. To get there, press F8 after the BIOS screen has passed.

Try [KillBox](http://www.killbox.net/).

Comment: does not work .... same error shows on Safe mode :(

Comment: @Azhar If this didn't work, why did you accept this answer? -1.

Comment: This is not the answer for OP or for me. The link provided in this answer is dead. If there is a problem with the path or filename then safe mode won't help you.

Answer (score 6):

This is not answered. Ironically, it is answered in the following thread which is marked as a duplicate of this question:

[Cannot delete a file: System cannot find the file specified](https://superuser.com/questions/787580/cannot-delete-a-file-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

I had this problem because I had generated folder names with a trailing space character, which Windows 7 does not handle gracefully. After trying all sorts of command line wizardry and obscure workarounds the thing that allowed me to delete the folder with trailing space was 7-zip, of all things. I clicked "Delete files after compression" and 7-zip was able to delete a folder that neither explorer.exe nor cmd.exe could.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it has a control char or other invisible character embedded in the name.  Try going to a command prompt and do a dir of the filename.  If it says it could not find it, use wildcards e.g. *foo* around part of the filename until it shows a directory listing for the one file.  Then use the same wildcards in the del command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267957/2622214, if you have Git installed on your windows machine, git bash enables you to use rm -rf .

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was using `rm -rf` in git bash.

0. download and install [git bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win) (obviously!)
1. open the containing folder in file explorer
2. right click on empty space
3. select "Open Git Bash Here"

before proceeding further, check if everything is correct. there won't be an undo.

4. `rm -rf folder-name`

a word of advice, use tab auto-completion to prevent typos and mistakes.

I tried deleting the folder in `cmd`, it gave me a "the system can not find the specified file". I also tried archiving the folder and checking the "delete after" option, that didn't work as well.