# Windows 10: How can I delete this huge (10 Gb) file?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, disk-space

This question looks like a duplicate, **but the answers don't work for me**:
[When I try to delete file in my PC it gives the error "Item not found"](https://superuser.com/questions/178422/when-i-try-to-delete-file-in-my-pc-it-gives-the-error-item-not-found)

I'm running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit with the Anniversary Update.

I do some video production and in my working directory, I've ended up with a strange huge file that's around 10 Gb.

[image]

I thought it was a temp file, but I can't delete it. I receive the message "Could not find this item."

[image]

Even on an Administrative Command Prompt, I get, "Could Not Find." If I delete using wildcards, `del s5sc*.*` I get `The system cannot find the file specified.`

[image]

I tried to "move" the file, but that didn't work.

[image]

Looking at the properties of the file, I get conflicting information.

[image]

I can't make any changes to the properties, security, attributes without seeing:

[image]

In addition to Windows showing that disk space being used, I scanned the directory with WinDirStat and it shows that disk space being used.

[image]

Running chkdsk shows no issues.

[image]

While learning *why* this is happening might be interesting, I'm more interested in recovering 10 Gb of disk space.

- I've tried using the free open source "Eraser" to delete it, but when I try to open the file in Eraser, nothing happens.
- I thought that maybe the file was "locked" so I tried to use IOBit's Unlocker. That had no effect on the file.
- I've tried all of these steps in Safe Mode.

**What do I need to do to get rid of this file?**

Comment: try to boot a linux live DVD and look if you can delete the file there

Comment: Does it still exist after a reboot?  What happens if you try `del s5s*.*` form a command-line?  Have you run a `chkdsk` to test your disk/file system for corruption yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I try to delete file in my PC it gives the error "Item not found"](http://superuser.com/questions/178422/when-i-try-to-delete-file-in-my-pc-it-gives-the-error-item-not-found), [Cannot delete a file: System cannot find the file specified](http://superuser.com/questions/787580/cannot-delete-a-file-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified?noredirect=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 this system has been rebooted several times, including after Windows Updates since I discovered this file. If you read my post, I have a screenshot of the command line attempt. I will try chkdsk and report back.

Comment: "I have a screenshot of the command line attempt"  I did, and you attempted to just delete the file by using the name you see.  Try it using the wildcard characters as I suggested. My guess is that the file name has an invalid character in it (as suggested in answers to the duplicates I pointed out)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 None of the answers on that other post work. I'm going to amend my answer with my Safe Mode findings.

Comment: Sound good, when you do update it, include _all_ things you've tried, and what the results were.

Comment: First thing you could try and do is add an extension to it. Your file name ends with a `.`. You could move the MP3 files up one directory and then try and delete the entire directory that contains `s5s.`. A surefire way to get rid of it would be to enable Bash on Ubuntu in Windows and delete it through the bash shell with the `rm -f` command

Comment: @DrZoo I've tried adding an extension. I've updated my question with that detail. Also to you and magicandre1981 about using Linux, there are a few complications with these options. Are there any Windows-based solutions?

Comment: I still thinks it's an invalid character. Check out the answers on this related question (and the ones it has marked as duplicates) for some methods to try: [How to delete a file that contains a backslash in the name under Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/409424/how-to-delete-a-file-that-contains-a-backslash-in-the-name-under-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The answers there are: 1) escape the character 2) use chkdsk 3) Linux boot. So, 1) I don't know which character to escape 2) chkdsk didn't seem to find problems 3) I don't have bootable media... I'm working on fixing that last one.

Comment: Mawcsco, what is the complication with the Windows Bash? You just need to [enable the Windows feature](http://superuser.com/questions/1108480/where-is-the-ubuntu-console-on-windows10/1108492#1108492) and then you open the bash console and run the command.

Comment: @DrZoo I wasn't aware of that feature or how to use it. Because I wasn't aware of it, I misunderstood your comment. I'm looking into it now

Comment: Make a usb bootable live linux distro. You can usu Rufus or Unetbootin. Browse and locate the file in question and delete from the live linux session. Recommend shift+del option. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @anonymouscoward, I know wading through the comments is difficult, but this has already been suggested and I don't currently have any bootable media. I'm working on it, but it can't happen soon. Though, It'd be great to have answers for a Windows problem that don't involve booting to a different operating system.

Comment: @DrZoo, that is pretty awesome. I can't believe I didn't know about this. I don't know why Windows command prompt couldn't delete this file, but Bash could. Please turn that into an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've had the same issue before too. In my case Windows cmd did not work either so I used MiniGW, which had no trouble blowing it away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Windows cmd has issues deleting the file, [enable Ubuntu's bash in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1108480/where-is-the-ubuntu-console-on-windows10/1108492#1108492) (a Windows native bash shell) to delete it.

To delete the file, navigate to the location of the file and run the command `rm -f filename` to remove it.

Comment: This is far easier to do than booting from a Linux distro. I'd venture installing Cygwin might be another way to do this.

Comment: @mawcsco yeah Cygwin is another option if you feel like going trough the installation.